# Check if a cookie array element exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, js-cookie

How can I check that an array element already exists within cookie?

Here is my code:

```
var cookieList = function (cookieName) {
    var cookie = Cookies.get(cookieName);
    var items = cookie ? cookie.split(/,/) : new Array();

    return {
        "add": function (val) {
            items.push(val);
            Cookies.set(cookieName, items.join(','), { path: '/' });
        }
    }
}

var list = new cookieList("MyItems");

$('.items').on('click', '.add', function () {
    var imageId = $(this).data("id");
    list.add(JSON.stringify(imageId));
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a method `exists` to `cookieList` and then check whether the passed value exists in the `items` array using `Array.indexOf()`

```
var cookieList = function (cookieName) {
    var cookie = Cookies.get(cookieName);
    var items = cookie ? cookie.split(/,/) : new Array();

    return {
        "add": function (val) {
            items.push(val);
            Cookies.set(cookieName, items.join(','), {
                path: '/'
            });
        },
        exists: function (val) {
            return items.indexOf(val) > -1
        }
    }
}

var list = new cookieList("MyItems");

$('.items').on('click', '.add', function () {
    var imageId = $(this).data("id");
    list.add(JSON.stringify(imageId));
    var exists = list.exists(JSON.stringify(imageId))
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/0trn7c3j/)

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, [js-cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) handles JSON out of the box:

```
var cookieList = function (cookieName) {
    var items = Cookies.getJSON(cookieName) || [];

    return {
        add: function (val) {
            items.push(val);
            Cookies.set(cookieName, items);
            // "path: /" is default,
            // see https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie/tree/v2.0.2#path
        },
        exists: function (val) {
            return items.indexOf(val) > -1
        }
    }
}

var list = new cookieList("MyItems");

$('.items').on('click', '.add', function () {
    var imageId = $(this).data("id");
    list.add(JSON.stringify(imageId));
    var exists = list.exists(JSON.stringify(imageId))
});
```

see https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie/tree/v2.0.2#json